# AmCharts Scraping Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, amcharts

I am trying to Scrape `AmCharts` Graph Values in JSON Object from  this [URL](https://eg.pricena.com/en/product/oppo-reno-5g-price-in-egypt)

Using the following command

```
driver.execute_script("AmCharts.charts[0].dataProvider")
```

In the script, it returns `None` while the browser console returns JSON object with the `AmCharts` Data

[image]

It appears like this in the web interface
[image]

How I can retrieve this dataProvider Array correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data do you want to scrape ?

Comment: Table Values `dataProvider` Array

Comment: I do not see any `//table` in entire page.

Comment: I meant the `Amchart` Graph , Updated my question with screenshot , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return` to your `execute_script` call in order to access the value in your script, e.g. `driver.execute_script("return AmCharts.charts[0].dataProvider")`

Full code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver_path = r"path/to/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://eg.pricena.com/en/product/oppo-reno-5g-price-in-egypt")

# scroll into the div so that the chart will render
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('product_pricechart').scrollIntoView()")

# wait until the chart div has been rendered before accessing the data provider
wait.until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_class_name("amcharts-chart-div").is_displayed())

# display chart data
print(driver.execute_script("return AmCharts.charts[0].dataProvider"))

driver.close()
```

Comment: Excellent.  Working as Expected

Answer (score 1):

The graph is not in Selenium view port, so first we will have to deal with vertical scrolling to the desired graph, and then I see `//*[name()='tspan']` xpath contains, horizontal and vertical values which is present in UI as well.

**Code:**

```
driver_path = r'D:\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://eg.pricena.com/en/product/oppo-reno-5g-price-in-egypt")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")

ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)

char_val = []
for elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='tspan']"):
    print(elem.text)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
Mar
May
Jul
Sep
Nov
Mar
May
Jul
Sep
Nov
5,000
5,500
6,000
6,500
7,000
7,500
8,000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Nice, This is a very good solution. How can I get the complete date if possible

Comment: what exactly did you mean by date ?

Comment: Please refer to the [link](https://ibb.co/WthXsH2) , hover on the graph and the full date appears

Comment: Do you have a rest url for this ? it would be very easy with rest.

Comment: The solution you provided gets the X-Axis Tick and Y-Axis Tick, I would like to get the values inside the graph and the dates of the JSON Data.

Comment: `AmCharts.charts[0].dataProvider`